# How to use columns value in order to generate another column's name for withColumn in Spark Scala

Tags: json, scala, dataframe, dynamic, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to generate dataframe after reading json resource file.My json file includes dependent attributes and while using withColumn, I need to get column value to create another column name.

You can find below what I am doing for now:

```
val getInfo= df
      .withColumn("transactions", explode($"transactions"))//this is array
      .withColumn("id", $"transactions.data.profile.id")
      .withColumn("totalAmounts", explode($"transactions.data.activity.total"))
      .withColumn("amount", $"totalAmounts.amount")
      .withColumn("code", $"totalAmounts.code")
      .withColumn("category", $"totalAmounts.category")
      .withColumn("createdAt", $"transactions.data.meta.created.at")
      .withColumn("relatedDetails", explode($"transactions.data.related"))
      .withColumn("resourceId", $"relatedDetails.id")
      .withColumn("mainType", $"relatedDetails.type")
      .withColumn("subType", $"transactions.data.subType")
      .drop("transactions")
      .drop("totalAmounts")
      .drop("relatedDetails")
      .as[TransactionData]
      .toDF()
```

Above code is OK for me but there is an attribute that is generated dynamically in the json file.
When I want to add another column "transactionType" which is dependent to value of "resourceId" column.

What I need to do is below :

```
.withColumn("transactionType",$"transactions.included.transactionDetail.<<resourceId value>>.transactionType")  .
```

Comment: Can you show an example of JSON?